# This Apple ID cannot be used for development with Xcode

Tags: xcode, apple-id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmOOc.png)

can someone help me ?
i was writing programs until yesterday xcode said me that "this apple id cannot be used for development with xcode"

what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Apple's [Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/) and signing in through there. It should ask you to accept some terms and conditions, and then you should be golden!